# Find real and distinct solutions

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Find real and distinct solutions to the equations
$$r^2+s^2=u^2+v^2$$ and $$r^3+s^3=u^3+v^3$$ 
I don't know how to solve this problem please help

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example (but there are lots of others) . . .

Let $r,s$ be the roots of the quadratic equation
$$x^2 - x - 1 = 0$$
and let $u,v$ be the roots of the quadratic equation
$$x^2 - ax + b = 0$$
where
\begin{align*}
a&=\frac{\sqrt{33}-1}{2}\\[4pt]
b&=\frac{11-\sqrt{33}}{4}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then $r,s,u,v$ satisfy
$$r^2 + s^2 = 3 = u^2 + v^2$$
$$r^3 + s^3 = 4 = u^3 + v^3$$